# Get step number in forever loop

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and want to improve with some exercices. 
One is here: https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/power-of-thor-episode-1

I solved this exercice with :

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

upDown l t 
    | l>t = ("S", (t+1))
    | t>l = ("N", (t-1))
    | otherwise = ("", t)

leftRight l t 
    | l>t = ("E", (t+1))
    | t>l = ("W", (t-1))
    |otherwise = ("", t)   

move lx tx ly ty 
    | lx==ly && tx==ty = []
    | otherwise =
    ((fst hb ++ fst gd) : move lx (snd gd) ly (snd hb) )
        where   gd = leftRight lx tx
                hb = upDown ly ty 

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- DO NOT REMOVE

    input_line <- getLine
    let input = words input_line
    let lightx = read (input!!0) :: Int -- the X position of the light of power
    let lighty = read (input!!1) :: Int -- the Y position of the light of power
    let initialtx = read (input!!2) :: Int -- Thor's starting X position
    let initialty = read (input!!3) :: Int -- Thor's starting Y position

    mapM_ putStrLn $ move lightx initialtx lighty initialty
```

I am very curious about the code template initially provided (see below).

**My questions are :**

- Is the following exercice just poorly translated from an procedural language ?
- I know how to generate the list of solution moves. How can I print them one by one in the forever loop ?

The initial template :

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- DO NOT REMOVE

    input_line <- getLine
    let input = words input_line
    let lightx = read (input!!0) :: Int -- the X position of the light of power
    let lighty = read (input!!1) :: Int -- the Y position of the light of power
    let initialtx = read (input!!2) :: Int -- Thor's starting X position
    let initialty = read (input!!3) :: Int -- Thor's starting Y position

    forever $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let remainingturns = read input_line :: Int -- The remaining amount of turns Thor can move. Do not remove this line.

        putStrLn "SE"
```

Note : we cannot use something like `initialValue - remainingturns` because we don't know the `initialValue`

Comment: Downvoter, if you can point out what my question is missing, I will gladly improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your data are immutable, and the only effectively updatable thing is the parameter list of a function, I would use it.

The idea:

```hs
move lx tx ly ty remainingTurns
  | remainingTurns < 1 = -- I don't know how do you signal an error.
  | ... move lx (snd gd) ly (snd hb) (remainingTurns - 1) ...
```

You can also consider including the number of steps remaining in the returned value.

Comment: AFAIU, this will return / print all value at each step of the `forever` loop, ( or print all then error at the first ). In both case it doesn't realy use the loop. Or did I miss something ?

Comment: You need to restart your recursive `move` invocation for every new iteration of the `forever` loop, don't you? The `remainingTurns` parameter serves to track the `move`'s invocations, not `main`'s. It's like the "accumulator parameter" typical for recursive algoritms.